# manually stop and re-start signalr's long polling?

Tags: signalr, long-polling, asp.net-mvc-5, bandwidth

i have an mvc-5 web application which has one view for a community chat. my current setup (IIS 7.5) allows long polling transport for signalR.

how to start the long-polling only if a user is on the specific chat view and to stop the long-polling requests when the user leaves the chat view?

..in order to save some bandwidth because the site is primarily intended for mobile users.

i already tried `connection.hub.stop()` and `connection.hub.start()` but the requests are still there (fiddler). what i am doing wrong?

thanks.

Comment: i'm afraid it's not so easy..

Comment: Calling stop should work

Comment: yes, a call to $.connection.hub.stop() seems to stop the connection because otherwise i get a "SignalR: Connection must be started before data can be sent. Call .start() before .send()" if i try to send a new message after i stopped the connection. but i still can see poll reqs in fiddler - even with the stopped connection! and if i close that browser window the requets are no more there!! please help :-)

Comment: its this tutorial which i take for beginning playing with signalr: http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/signalr-20/getting-started-with-signalr-20/tutorial-getting-started-with-signalr-20-and-mvc-5  and there i added a stop-button with a simple:  $('#stop').click(function () {$.connection.hub.stop();$('#discussion').append('<li><strong>disconnected</strong></li>');});  after clicking the stop-button the poll requests remain, not so when closing the ie-window -> then the requets dissapear (fiddler).

Comment: i just want to achive data is transferred only when the user is on the chat view!

Comment: Close fiddler. It's likely keeping the connection open longer than it needs to be. Can you show which connection is still active in the fiddler trace?

Comment: the requests are still there, even if fiddler was closed and started after a click on the stop-btn:   http://localhost:6967/760bacbf04ca4e96a0c85f693a72d8df/arterySignalR/poll?transport=longPolling&connectionToken=AQAAA...<DATA>..HL%2FUtTg%3D%3D&messageId=d-3403796E-B5%2C0%7CB_%2C4%7CB%3A%2C0&requestUrl=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A42833%2F&browserName=InternetExplorer&tid=4&_=1387838316222

Comment: That's browser link (http://gunnarpeipman.com/2013/07/browser-link/). It uses SignalR, that's a VS feature that you can turn off.

Comment: Thank you dfowler, have nice holidays!